# Flash AS3 square root?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I can't do this: How can I get a number of displacement (movieclip)?

Example: MovieClip.x == 0 and MovieClip.y == 0

Then I move it.

MovieClip.x == 50 and MovieClip.y == -90

Now if I make a tween, what is the number of displacement (moving)?

Comment: can you clarify your question, as I'm not sure what you mean by "number of displacement" or what it has to do with the question title "Flash AS3 square root"

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a guess and interpret the question to be something like, "How far as the MovieClip moved (or been displaced)?".

The answer would then be: 102.956 -> 103 units (pixels). You can use the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to figure this out:

```
xDist = 50 - 0
yDist = -90 - 0
distanceTraveled = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist))
```

Which would link as to why the poster asked about sqaure root.

Use [Math.sqrt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#sqrt%28%29) to take the sqaure root of a number.